# Generating points in rectangle

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, uniform-spaces

I am trying to generate $N$ points randomly and uniformly distributed in an $m \times n$ rectangle. How can this be done? I have tried to split the initial rectangle into as many rectangles i could, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For each point, independently generate two numbers: $l_i\sim U(0,m)$ and $h_i\sim U(0,n)$. The resulting point $(l_i,h_i)$ is a point in the rectangle and the joint distribution is uniform over the entire rectangle.

Comment: could you prove the distribution is uniform ? To me, you're taking the uniform distribution on a square, and stretch it to a rectangle. Unlikely to produce a uniform distribution on the rectangle (e.g., consider a highly stretched rectangle)

Comment: The joint density on the rectangle is the product of the densities $\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{mn}$. Thus the density is uniform over the entire rectangle.